# how to remove space more than one column inside primefaces

Tags: primefaces

I have created a table using PrimeFaces html tag inside each column I have included an inputText.

How can I remove the spaces between the inputTexts?

***xhtml***

```or-tag-here
 <div>
    <table width="100%" style="border:1px solid #2d6282;">  
       <tr>
          <td align="left" > <h:inputText value="#{facility.name}"     style="width:233px"/></td>
          <td align="left"><h:inputText value="#{facility.clientName}"   style="width: 119px"/></td>
          <td align="left"><h:inputText value="#{facility.currentAddress}"   style="width: 130px"/></td>
          <td align="left"><h:inputText value="#{facility.cityState}"   style="width: 100px"/></td>
          <td align="left"><h:inputText value="#{facility.zipCode}"   style="width: 50px"/></td>
          <td align="left"><h:inputText value="#{facility.countryCode}"   style="width: 70px"/></td>
          <td align="left"><h:inputText value="#{facility.currentContact}"   style="width: 60px"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
 </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Hatem Alimam sir please help i have apply input box bottom of every column of table but i unable to remove the space among column

Comment: hi any one please help

Comment: Take a look at the CSS styles of this components in your browser. For example with Firebug. Looks like there is a padding or margin at one of the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `style="width:233px"` form each and every column, keep table row `width="100%"` your input box will auto adjust. but in that case your input box will be equal size.
let me know if you want something else.

Comment: no ankush sir i have got same output no change when remove style="width:233px" every column